# HERE API: Transit Route API walking polyline?

Tags: here-api

How can I request graph (for drawing polyline) in walking section of Transit Route API?

Here are walking section from JSON Transit Route API result:

```
{
                "id": "R00133e-C2-S0",
                "mode": 20,
                "Dep": {
                  "time": "2019-09-15T09:18:00",
                  "Addr": {
                    "y": 21.011375,
                    "x": 105.808079
                  },
                  "Transport": {
                    "mode": 20
                  }
                },
                "Journey": {
                  "distance": 617,
                  "duration": "PT10M"
                },
                "Arr": {
                  "time": "2019-09-15T09:28:00",
                  "Stn": {
                    "y": 21.009895,
                    "x": 105.812835,
                    "name": "470 ABC",
                    "id": "702830459"
                  }
                }
              },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need just need to ad the parameter **graph**:

Requests coordinate pairs to allow the drawing of a polyline for the route. The
possible values are:
1 (enabled), 0 (disabled)
The default is 0.

With &graph=1 you will retrieve the walking segment of the route in a form of sequence of coordinates.

Comment: Yes, I did add the parameter graph=1. But the walking section still has no graph field. Maybe it depends on the country?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did add the parameter graph=1. But the walking section still has no graph field. Maybe it depends on the country?